# Plotting markers in folium using pandas issues with float64

Tags: python, pandas, folium

Let me share my original json file first:

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "awy_id": "",
            "distance": 0.0,
            "fl_at_wpt": 1,
            "lat": -34.821666,
            "lng": -58.536666,
            "max_fl": 410,
            "min_fl": 0,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "SAEZ",
            "ndid_ext": "SAEZ",
            "ndtyp": "PA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "PA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": false,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "GBE6",
            "distance": 84661.59842290805,
            "fl_at_wpt": 322,
            "lat": -35.751666,
            "lng": -58.465,
            "max_fl": 1000,
            "min_fl": 0,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "GBE",
            "ndid_ext": "GBE",
            "ndtyp": "D",
            "ndtyp_ext": "D",
            "special_route": "GBE6",
            "through_fra_edge": false,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 146604.93487805585,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -37.0,
            "lng": -59.0,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "",
            "ndid": "3700S05900W",
            "ndid_ext": "3700S05900W",
            "ndtyp": "$C",
            "ndtyp_ext": "$C",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 156860.1442784719,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -38.313333,
            "lng": -59.656666,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "SIGUL",
            "ndid_ext": "SIGUL",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 253654.31159714353,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -40.49,
            "lng": -60.551666,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "PUGLI",
            "ndid_ext": "PUGLI",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "UT662",
            "distance": 455742.1357395189,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -44.38,
            "lng": -62.313333,
            "max_fl": 450,
            "min_fl": 250,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "OGRAX",
            "ndid_ext": "OGRAX",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": false,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 172690.29386362626,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -45.846666,
            "lng": -63.038333,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "ESNAS",
            "ndid_ext": "ESNAS",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 268007.5486955521,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -48.113333,
            "lng": -64.238333,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "IRAVA",
            "ndid_ext": "IRAVA",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 201521.2136195075,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -49.81,
            "lng": -65.205,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "LOBOS",
            "ndid_ext": "LOBOS",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "UT662",
            "distance": 355978.6689666387,
            "fl_at_wpt": 400,
            "lat": -52.788333,
            "lng": -67.071666,
            "max_fl": 450,
            "min_fl": 250,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "ERUPO",
            "ndid_ext": "ERUPO",
            "ndtyp": "EA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "EA",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": false,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 120043.42891043477,
            "fl_at_wpt": 210,
            "lat": -53.785,
            "lng": -67.76,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "GRA",
            "ndid_ext": "GRA",
            "ndtyp": "DB",
            "ndtyp_ext": "DB",
            "special_route": "",
            "through_fra_edge": true,
            "used_fl": 400
        },
        {
            "awy_id": "DCT",
            "distance": 122840.72073640439,
            "fl_at_wpt": 2,
            "lat": -54.843333,
            "lng": -68.295,
            "max_fl": 660,
            "min_fl": 95,
            "ndic": "SA",
            "ndid": "SAWH",
            "ndid_ext": "SAWH",
            "ndtyp": "PA",
            "ndtyp_ext": "PA",
            "special_route": "DCT",
            "through_fra_edge": false,
            "used_fl": 400
        }
    ]}
```

I have been trying to use a pandasDataFrame columns 'lat','lng' to plot markers using folium.

lat and long are : "dtype: float64"

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
import json

with open('response.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['entries'])
af = pd.DataFrame(data['profile'])

difference = af.diff(axis=0)
difference.drop([0],inplace=False)
difference

#df[df.select_dtypes(np.float64).columns] = df.select_dtypes(np.float64).astype(np.float32)
flight = folium.Map(
    location=[38.40, -30.40],
    zoom_start=2
)
for _, city in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker(
        location=[df['lng'], df['lat']]
    ).add_to(flight)

flight
```

After I run the code, I get an error as such :
`Name: lng, dtype: float64 of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> is not convertible to float.`

I have tried searching for a solution, I've tried to convert the lat and lng column to float, but that didnt seem to do the trick.

" df[df.select_dtypes(np.float64).columns] = df.select_dtypes(np.float64).astype(np.float) "

Is there anything that I am missing , or could I get some guidance on how to deal with this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Never post picture of textual data. This is counter productive and prevent the community to help you. Copy paste instead the sampled dataset in order to have a [mcve].

Comment: Is the code looping through the data frame incorrect?
The correct code is `folium.Marker(location=[city['lng'], city['lat']]).add_to(flight)`

Comment: I found a solution.

```
X = df[['lat', 'lng', 'ndid']].copy()
# mark each station as a point
for index, row in X.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['lat'], row['lng']],
                        radius=3,
                        popup=row['ndid'],
                        ).add_to(flight)```
did the trick